# How to create link in grails webflow without execution state in url?

Tags: grails, spring-webflow, gsp

I want to display an image in my webflow wich comes from my domain object.

The domain object has an byte[] Array holding an image. The "image" method in my controller delivers the image to browser. This works fine.

In my webflow I'm doing this:

```
<img src="${createLink(controller:'shop', action:'image', id:shopInstance.id)}">
```

I can see the image in my frontend (in browser) but it reloads each time i click "next" or change my state in webflow because the image url contains a param that changes each event in webflow.

The created image url (example above) looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/project/shop/image/2?execution=e2s5
```

I don't want that the execution param is delivered into my image url. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're getting that execution param but you could try: `<img src="${resource(dir: 'shop/image', file: shopInstance.id)}">` and make sure the UrlMappings.groovy file has a mapping for 'ship/image' to the proper controller.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that this is a bug. A work around I used is the following

```
${createLink(controller: 'controller', action: 'action').replaceAll(/\?.*$/, "")}
```

This will use a regex to remove the execution parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As of Grails 2.0.4, look at ApplicationTagLib.groovy, you can see

```
if (request['flowExecutionKey']) {
    params."execution" = request['flowExecutionKey']
    urlAttrs.params = params
    if (attrs.controller == null && attrs.action == null && attrs.url == null && attrs.uri == null) {
        urlAttrs[LinkGenerator.ATTRIBUTE_ACTION] = GrailsWebRequest.lookup().actionName
    }
}
```

So Grails is forcing every link rendered within webflow to include that execution params. It looks like bug to me.